# Error Deleting Document Type

Tags: c#, umbraco6, document-types

I  am getting a weird error on an Umbraco site I maintain. I'm trying to delete an old Document Type that I am replacing with an updated one. The error I am getting is:

> **Error handling action** Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'textpage' Key being added: 'textpage'

The document type is not called "textpage" and doesn’t have any link to "textpage" that I can see. There are no physical files on the server and this error didn’t happen on the staging site nor did it occur on my local test. So I am a little stumped!

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** This is also occurring if I try to save any document type in the CMS.

Comment: i assume you've seen this thread? https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/15077-Umbraco-Dictionairy-Error-Item-has-already-been-added-

check the bottom answer

Comment: But I don't have any duplicate templates.

Comment: Burgi - have you actually examined the db to check for duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a cache issue. Try touching the web.config file and see if the issue goes away.

Another thing that can cause this is if you have multiple templates with the same alias. Check for that as well.

Comment: I have added a few linebreaks to the `Web.config` with no change. I also rebuilt the website cache. I have also already stated that there are no identically named templates.